# tspath collects incorrect paths

Tags: typescript, module

I have an express application that I develop with typescript, I want to use relative paths, without using tspath, because it doesn't work correctly. Here I will give a couple of examples of his mistakes.

my [tsconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb3HD.png).v1 -> [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufnUt.png) -> [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHvBg.png) Here I am getting error during dev process in my ts file, and my output file correct

my [tsconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPn80.png).v2 -> [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8mL9.png) -> [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilCRN.png) But this time I get wrong path in my output file :D

if i try use this [tsconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYnow.png).v3 i get next error [errorLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtNpO.png)

Tell me, are there any alternatives, or is my tsconfig not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative, this is [tscpaths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tscpaths), the name is very similar, but they have at least some instructions that helped me build my output project well